# The result of code coverage

Tags: jestjs

Recently I am working on writing jest unit tests for my company's application. After that, I try to run code coverage report in order to trace which file does not have better coverage. However, I find one confusing point which is that the coverage percentage is not accurate as what I expect.

For example, if I have a file called A. In A, I import a third party library called B. Even though I write a fully-covered test for A, I do not get 100% code coverage. The reason is that since A depends on B and B does not have 100% tests, the calculation of code coverage would count B.

So, do you have any idea about how to get code coverage which excludes those dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude specific paths or files from coverage reporting.

In my specific case, I don't want for files in `app/dependecies` folder to show up in coverage report so I have them excluded (see the `!` before path)  in `package.json` file:

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": ["!app/dependencies/**"]
}
```

Instead of configuring `jest` in `package.json` file, you can use other option described here - https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html